# reindex sorted pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
    Column A    Column B    Date       Value
1          A           1   2011-01-01   10
2          B           1   2011-01-01   10
3          A           2   2011-01-01   10
4          B           2   2011-01-01   10
5          A           1   2011-01-02   10
6          B           1   2011-01-02   10
7          A           2   2011-01-02   10
8          B           2   2011-01-02   10
9          A           1   2011-01-03   10
10         B           1   2011-01-03   10
11         B           2   2011-01-03   10
```

I want to find missing dates for every value of A and B (in this case, it would be A, date: 2011-01-03), and insert NaN there. I tried the reindex function:

```
df.sort_values(['Column A','Column B'],ascending = [True,True], inplace = True)
df.index = range(1,len(df)+1)
dates = pd.date_range('2011-01-01','2011-01-03')
df = df.reindex(dates, fill_value = None)
print df
```

But it gives me NaN in every column. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can flag these missing values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.set_index(['Column A', 'Column B', 'Date']).unstack().stack(dropna=False).sort_index(level=[2, 0]).reset_index()

   Column A  Column B        Date  Value
0         A         1  2011-01-01   10.0
1         B         1  2011-01-01   10.0
2         A         2  2011-01-01   10.0
3         B         2  2011-01-01   10.0
4         A         1  2011-01-02   10.0
5         B         1  2011-01-02   10.0
6         A         2  2011-01-02   10.0
7         B         2  2011-01-02   10.0
8         A         1  2011-01-03   10.0
9         B         1  2011-01-03   10.0
10        A         2  2011-01-03    NaN
11        B         2  2011-01-03   10.0
```

#### Note: row 10 has the missing value NaN

Comment: This doesn't give me the missing value. I want a row for the missing value to be added whose Value will be NaN

Comment: I believe this takes care of that.

Comment: You are correct, the values had not persisted. Thanks for the solution